# Are there any syntax or way that is similar to GOTO in Matlab in this situation?

Tags: matlab, loops, goto

**with the excel file is**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sd2uL.jpg)

```
clc;close all;clear all;
[~,Spot]= xlsread('parkingspot.xlsx','A1:B4');
while spotcheck == 1
list = {'A1','A2','A3','A4','B1','B2','B3','B4'};
[pick,tf] = listdlg('PromptString',{'Select a Parking Spot.',...
    'Checking if slot still available.',''},...
    'SelectionMode','single','ListString',list);
switch pick
    case 1
        pick = 'A1';
    case 2
        pick = 'A2';
    case 3
        pick = 'A3';
    case 4
        pick = 'A4';
    case 5
        pick = 'B1';
    case 6
        pick = 'B2';
    case 7
        pick = 'B3';
    case 8
        pick = 'B4';
end
notice1=['You have picked ' pick ' checking availability, please wait...'];
disp(notice1);
%check availabilty
spotcheck = strcmp(Spot,'V');
        notice3=[pick ' status is UNAVAILABLE, please choose another spot.'];
        disp(notice3);
        pick =choose();
end
xlswrite('parkingspot.xlsx','V',1,pick);
notice2=[pick ' status is AVAILABLE, please proceed to the spot'];
disp(notice2)
```

and it show this error:
**Unrecognized function or variable 'spotcheck'.
Error in checkspot2 (line 3)
while spotcheck == 1**

Are there any way that at the last "else" that i can go back to the choosing Switch Cases if the value of spotcheck = 1 therefore create a loop until the spotcheck value = 1?
Thank you.

Comment: You can use an infinite while loop

Comment: can you please be more specific? because i have tried and it didnt work

Comment: `while true` and `end` with your code in between. What have you tried that didn't work? Please create a [mre].

Comment: i just edited to like you advice but it didnt seem to work

Comment: `spotcheck` is not defined when you first query its value. Simply give it a value before the loop: `spotcheck = 1; while spotcheck==1, ...`

Comment: Operator '==' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'.
i got this error instead